# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.store.dispatch')

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, vue-native

I'm working on a mobile application that uses an API to login but whenever I try to login I get the following error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.store.dispatch')
```

The code that causes the error looks like this:

```
try {
        this.store.dispatch('user/UPDATE_ACCESS_TOKEN', {
            token: response.access_token,
            ttl: response.access_token_expires_in
        })
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: It means that either `this` or `this.store` is `undefined`

Comment: could you show your main.js where you define new Vue....